# How to omit rows with NA in only two columns in R?

Tags: r, na

I want to omit rows where `NA` appears in *both* of *two* columns.

I'm familiar with `na.omit`, `is.na`, and `complete.cases`, but can't figure out how to use these to get what I want. For example, I have the following dataframe:

```
(df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA),
                     y = c(4L, 5L, NA, 6L, 7L),
                     z = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, NA)),
                .Names = c("x", "y", "z"),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -5L)))
x   y   z
1   4   8
2   5   9
NA  NA  10
3   6   11
NA  7   NA
```

and I want to remove **only** those rows where `NA`appears in both the `x` and `y` columns (excluding anything in z), to give

```
x   y   z
1   4   8
2   5   9
3   6   11
NA  7   NA
```

Does anyone know an easy way to do this? Using `na.omit`, `is.na`, or `complete.cases` is not working.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
df[!with(df,is.na(x)& is.na(y)),]
#      x y  z
#1  1 4  8
#2  2 5  9
#4  3 6 11
#5 NA 7 NA
```

I did benchmarked on a slightly bigger dataset. Here are the results:

```
set.seed(237)
df <- data.frame(x=sample(c(NA,1:20), 1e6, replace=T), y= sample(c(NA, 1:10), 1e6, replace=T), z= sample(c(NA, 5:15), 1e6,replace=T)) 

f1 <- function() df[!with(df,is.na(x)& is.na(y)),]
f2 <- function() df[rowSums(is.na(df[c("x", "y")])) != 2, ]
f3 <- function()  df[ apply( df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))>1 ), ] 

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit="relative")
Unit: relative
#expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# f1()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100
# f2()  1.044812  1.068189  1.138323  1.129611  0.856396   100
# f3() 26.205272 25.848441 24.357665 21.799930 22.881378   100
```

Comment: Thanks akrun - i used your answer as it was shortest, but selected another as it was posted first.  thanks again. :)

Comment: @Thomas, please don't change the accepted answer based on those parameters. If akrun's answer is what you were looking for (which it sounds like it is), they should get the credit for it. My FGITW reference was just a poke at your method of deciding which answer to select. The main advantage of my answer is its ease of application to more than just a handful of columns.

Comment: Okie Dokie!  :) changed answer back to akrun!

Comment: @Thomas, Based on the parameter you described, this should got to Amanda Mahto.  Sorry, for being late in the discussion.

Comment: @Thomas, in case you're interested, I've updated my answer to show what I was referring to about the ease of application of the `rowSums` + `is.na` approach I had suggested.

Answer (score 16):

`dplyr` solution

```
require("dplyr")
df %>% filter_at(.vars = vars(x, y), .vars_predicate = any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

can be modified to take any number columns using the `.vars` argument

---

**Update: `dplyr 1.0.4`**

```r
df %>%
  filter(!if_all(c(x, y), is.na))
```

See similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136167/6105259

Answer (score 8):

Use `rowSums` with `is.na`, like this:

```
> df[rowSums(is.na(df[c("x", "y")])) != 2, ]
   x y  z
1  1 4  8
2  2 5  9
4  3 6 11
5 NA 7 NA
```

---

Jumping on the benchmarking wagon, and demonstrating what I was referring to about this being a fairly easy-to-generalize solution, consider the following:

```
## Sample data with 10 columns and 1 million rows
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(c(NA, 1:20), 
                                      1e6, replace = TRUE)))
```

First, here's what things look like if you're just interested in two columns. Both solutions are pretty legible and short. Speed is quite close.

```
f1 <- function() {
  df[!with(df, is.na(X1) & is.na(X2)), ]
} 
f2 <- function() {
  df[rowSums(is.na(df[1:2])) != 2, ]
} 

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), times = 20)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  f1() 745.8378 1100.764 1128.047 1199.607 1310.236    20
#  f2() 784.2132 1101.695 1125.380 1163.675 1303.161    20
```

Next, let's look at the same problem, but this time, we are considering `NA` values across the first 5 columns. At this point, the `rowSums` approach is slightly faster and the syntax does not change much.

```
f1_5 <- function() {
  df[!with(df, is.na(X1) & is.na(X2) & is.na(X3) &
             is.na(X4) & is.na(X5)), ]
} 
f2_5 <- function() {
  df[rowSums(is.na(df[1:5])) != 5, ]
} 

microbenchmark(f1_5(), f2_5(), times = 20)
# Unit: seconds
#    expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  f1_5() 1.275032 1.294777 1.325957 1.368315 1.572772    20
#  f2_5() 1.088564 1.169976 1.193282 1.225772 1.275915    20
```

Comment: Hi Ananda Mahto, I'm not sure what you mean but akrun's answer was posted first.

Comment: thanks Ananda, I selected your answer as it was posted first.

Answer (score 8):

You can apply to slice up the rows:

```
sel <- apply( df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))>1 )
```

Then you can select with that:

```
df[ sel, ]
```

To ignore the z column, just omit it from the apply:

```
sel <- apply( df[,c("x","y")], 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))>1 )
```

If they all have to be `TRUE`, just change the function up a little:

```
sel <- apply( df[,c("x","y")], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)) )
```

The other solutions here are more specific to this particular problem, but `apply` is worth learning as it solves many other problems.  The cost is speed (usual caveats about small datasets and speed testing apply):

```
> microbenchmark( df[!with(df,is.na(x)& is.na(y)),], df[rowSums(is.na(df[c("x", "y")])) != 2, ], df[ apply( df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))>1 ), ] )
Unit: microseconds
                                              expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
              df[!with(df, is.na(x) & is.na(y)), ]  67.148  71.5150  76.0340  86.0155 1049.576   100
        df[rowSums(is.na(df[c("x", "y")])) != 2, ] 132.064 139.8760 145.5605 166.6945  498.934   100
 df[apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) > 1), ] 175.372 184.4305 201.6360 218.7150  321.583   100
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: No problem.  You got some great answers to a relatively simple question, which says something good about your ability to ask questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is also the very basic `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!(is.na(x) & is.na(y)))

   x y  z
1  1 4  8
2  2 5  9
3  3 6 11
4 NA 7 NA
```