# Using filter() with across() to keep all rows of a data frame that include a missing value for any variable

Tags: r, dplyr, r4epi

Sometimes I want to view all rows in a data frame that will be dropped if I drop all rows that have a missing value for any variable. In this case, I'm specifically interested in how to do this with `dplyr` 1.0's `across()` function used inside of the `filter()` verb.

Here is an example data frame:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~x, ~y,
  1, 1, 0,
  2, 1, 1,
  3, NA, 1,
  4, 0, 0,
  5, 1, NA
)
```

Code for keeping rows that *DO NOT* include any missing values is provided on the [tidyverse website](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html). Specifically, I can use:

```
df %>% 
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~ !is.na(.x)
    )
  )
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0
2     2     1     1
3     4     0     0
```

However, I can't figure out how to return the opposite -- rows *with* a missing value in any variable. The result I'm looking for is:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3    NA     1
2     5     1    NA
```

My first thought was just to remove the `!`:

```
df %>% 
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~ is.na(.x)
    )
  )
```

But, that returns zero rows.

Of course, I can get the answer I want with this code if I know all variables that have a missing value ahead of time:

```
df %>% 
  filter(is.na(x) | is.na(y))
```

But, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to know which variables have a missing value ahead of time. Additionally, I'm aware of how to do this with the `filter_all()` function:

```
df %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(is.na(.)))
```

But, the `filter_all()` function has been superseded by the use of `across()` in an existing verb. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html

Other unsuccessful attempts I've made are:

```
df %>% 
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~any_vars(is.na(.x))
    )
  )

df %>% 
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~!!any_vars(is.na(.x))
    )
  )

df %>% 
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~!!any_vars(is.na(.))
    )
  )

df %>% 
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~any(is.na(.x))
    )
  )

df %>% 
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~any(is.na(.))
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's now possible with `dplyr` 1.0.4. The new `if_any()` replaces `across()` for the filtering use-case.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(~ id, ~ x, ~ y,
              1, 1, 0,
              2, 1, 1,
              3, NA, 1,
              4, 0, 0,
              5, 1, NA)

df %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), is.na))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>      id     x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3    NA     1
#> 2     5     1    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

See here for more details: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/

Comment: can this be used to filter for strings that are empty? I tried `filter(if_any(everything(), ""))` but it does not work

Comment: @sourlemonaid, you should supply a function inside `if_any()`, but just  `""` isn't a function. So you can create one: `is_empty <- function(x) x == ""` and then `filter(if_any(everything(), is_empty))`

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have worked

Answer (score 5):

We can use `reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
      filter(across(everything(), is.na) %>% reduce(`|`))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#     id     x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3    NA     1
#2     5     1    NA
```

Comment: Thank you, @akrun! I really appreciate you response and your answer definitely works. However, doesn't it feel somewhat unsatisfying? Shouldn't this be more straightforward?

Comment: @BradCannell. You are right.  I also felt sometime back that the replacement for `filter_at` with `any_vars/all_vars` is not clear when we use `across`.  I hope the next release of `dplyr` would fix these

Comment: I think I figured out why across() feels a little uncomfortable for me. I think it's because in my mind `across()` should only select the columns to be operated on (in the spirit of each function does one thing). In reality, `across()` is used to select the columns to be operated on and to receive the operation to execute. For me, I think `across()` would feel more natural if it could be used like, for example:
`df %>% group_by(g1, g2) %>% summarise(across(a:d), mean)` instead of: `df %>% group_by(g1, g2) %>% summarise(across(a:d, mean))`. I'm sure there was a good reason though.

Comment: @BradCannell Thanks, I also think in that way.  It would be better to suggest in their github page regarding the modification of behaviors so that they would take notice of it and change if they find it more natural

Comment: Thank you! Concise and clear. IMO this is the best solution for pre-1.0.4 dplyr.

Answer (score 4):

HanOostdijk replied on the [RStudio Community website](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-filter-with-across-to-keep-all-rows-of-a-data-frame-that-include-a-missing-value-for-any-variable/68442/2) with a solution that uses the `across()` function. He writes:

"In the same article you mention [tidyverse website](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html) there is 'a trick' with the rowSums function. You can use that as:"

```
rowAny <- function(x) {
  rowSums(x) > 0
} 

df %>% 
  filter(
    rowAny(
      across(
       .cols = everything(),
       .fns = ~ is.na(.x)
      )
    )
  )
```

@akrun points out in the comments below that this can be made more compact as:

```
df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(across(everything(), ~ is.na(.))) > 0)
```

Comment: Adding some commentary here because I didn't feel like it was appropriate to mix it in with the solution. I'll say again, the solution above works. So, thank you @HanOostdijk! However, it feels unsatisfying to me. For me, `dplyr` has always been about simplifying code and making it easier to read. The code above does not feel easy to read to me, and it seems like it's more verbose than it should need to be. Don't get me wrong, I'm a huge fan of `dplyr` and the `tidyverse`, but as of this moment, `across()` doesn't feel like an improvement over `_if`, `_at`, and `_all`. I hope it grows on me!

Comment: I first thought of posting the `rowSums` trick but then I thought I should just stick to `dplyr` because of what you just said, code readability. I agree, at this time `across` does not seem like a significant improvement over previous options. And yes, this code is not pleasant to read.

Comment: You could make this more compact `df  %>% filter(rowSums(across(everything(), ~ is.na(.))) > 0)`. I believe the `any_vars`, `all_vars` with `filter` would change in the future

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on this. My understanding of the new `across()` function is that it operates on columns, not rows. So when you run this code you don't get anything becuase

```r
df %>% 
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~ is.na(.x)
    )
  )

# A tibble: 0 x 3
# … with 3 variables: id <dbl>, x <dbl>, y <dbl>
```

it essentially create three logical columns in the background to check the presence of element-wise `NA`, it then probably compute a final logical column on which it operates the filter command. Now this final column will have `TRUE` only if all the columns are `TRUE` for `is.na()`. To test my hypothesis, I added another row in your data that has all `NA` in all three columns. And when I run your code as is, I get that row as an output because now the corresponding row will generate a `TRUE` in that final logical vector. Now I don't know if this is how `across()` works exactly but this makes sense to me.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~x, ~y,
  1, 1, 0,
  2, 1, 1,
  3, NA, 1,
  4, 0, 0,
  5, 1, NA,
  NA,NA,NA
)

df %>% 
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~ is.na(.x)
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      id     x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    NA    NA    NA
```

so in order for this to work with your original data, I would use `rowwise()` and `c_across()` (rowwise version of `across()`) as follows

```r
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  filter(
    is.na(sum(c_across(everything())))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id     x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3    NA     1
#> 2     5     1    NA

df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  filter(
    any(is.na(c_across(everything())))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id     x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3    NA     1
#> 2     5     1    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, @cropgen. I appreciate that you were able to submit a `dplyr`-only solution. But doesn't just feel like there should be a solution that works directly in `across()`?

Comment: Yes, I really hoped that `across()` should work but sadly it doesn't or I don't know how to use it.

Comment: No, `c_across()` is appropriate here. You use `across()` when you want to treat the columns as vectors and `c_across()` when you want to treat the rows as vectors. In this case, I want to apply `is.na %>% any` to each row vector, so that's why I use `c_across()`. Horizontal operations like this are precisely why the `c_across()` function was created.

Answer (score 3):

or

```
df %>% anti_join(df %>% drop_na())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it might help to use

`setdiff(df, df %>% drop_na())`

to get the result you want.

This does not use *across()*, but gets the job done in a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this using only base R:

```
df[apply(is.na.data.frame(df), 1, any), ]
```

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
> df %>% filter(!complete.cases(.))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3    NA     1
2     5     1    NA
```

or simply

```
df[!complete.cases(df), ]
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible just invert the output of `across()`. Otherwise it would be as easy as

```
df %>% 
  filter( !across( everything(), ~!is.na(.) ) )
```

This reminds me, in JMP there is an option "Invert row selection". Maybe in R we need an inverted filter() too? Something like this:

```
anti_filter <- function(.data, ...){
  anti_join(.data, filter(.data, ...))
}
```

and then - a miracle:

```
df %>% anti_filter(across(everything(), ~!is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3    NA     1
2     5     1    NA
```